# Add a map into jenkins build flow plugin as a parameters

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-build-flow

I have a question about jenkins build flow plugin.

There is a default value called params in build flow dsl which looks like a map.

What I want to do is pass this map to the jobs I want to build later, however, build flow dont accept a map as a parameters.
For example:
build("test_job", params)

The most stupid way I know is just paste all of them one by one, like, build("test_job", "Key1":params[1], "key2":"params[2]")

Any better idea for this case?

Br,
Tim

Answer (score 1):

The order is the key here!
You can do this (at least it works for me), use the map of parameters as the first argument :

```
job_params = [:]
job_params['BRANCH'] = 'The Branch Name'

build( job_params, 'pipelinetester' )
```

And it works!

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
build("jobname", parameter_name:"your parameter value")
```

Example :

In your case if you are using name as parameter and your value "abc"
then use

```
build ("job-name", name:"abc")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by archiving your map from project 1 and copy it using this plugin:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin

Or you can use shared folder using the plugin:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/CopyArchiver+Plugin